# When can we have night mode?

Tags: feature-request

My eyes burn. I'm not used to this amount of light at all. I'm either blind or stupid because I can't find the toggle anywhere.

Comment: This is currently only available on Stack Overflow. There's a link to a blog post explaining why, in this previous question -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412644/is-stack-overflow-the-only-stack-exchange-site-that-has-a-dark-theme-option-why